# How Windows SVN limits file upload size

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

My environment: Windows visualsvn
How to limit the size of a user to upload a file. I hope you can get your help.

Comment: In order to get any sort of response, this question needs much more detail and specificity. At the moment, this question is extremely vague and broad.

Comment: I'm flagging to close as too broad because necessary details were asked for half an hour ago yet the OP has not taken any interest in fixing the question.

Answer (score 0):

VisualSVN Server does not limit the size of a commit. Make sure that you run an up to date server and client version and that an antivirus or proxy does not make the client drop the connection.

Note that you can always contact support@visualsvn.com for assistance.